# Java font doesn't render

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I'm trying to use a custom fon, but for some reason it doesn't render and no exceptions are thrown either.
I already looked through other similar questions where the solution was adding it to the Graphics Environment which I did.

```
public static Font font;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    try{
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("myFont.ttf"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ex");
    }
    GraphicsEnvironment ge =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(font);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main ex = new Main();
            ex.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

I then use this font later,

```
public void draw(Graphics g, ImageObserver o){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, (int) Board.w, (int) Board.h, o);
        New.draw(g2d,o);
        Load.draw(g2d,o);
        Quit.draw(g2d,o);
        g2d.setFont(Main.font);
        g2d.drawString("Test Text",0,0);
    }
```

But there is simply nothing there.

EDIT: I have added

```
    JList fonts = new JList( ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames() );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(fonts));
```

from the same example that suggested registering the font and I can see my font there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
try{
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("myFont.ttf"));
    font = font.deriveFont(30F);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

where '30F' is a float type for font size.

Comment: Didn't help, it's still not there.

Comment: @seMikel and in `g2d.drawString("Test Text",0,0);` did you tried to change `0,0` to other value? It would be easier with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did initially have other numbers, just thought this would be the better value for some reason. Btw I tried also adding your solution in the draw function itself and it worked! So thank you very much.